# User authentication in Chrome extension for rails app with devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, devise

My Chrome extension aims to allow a user to create a bookmark (url, title etc.) of the current tab and send it to a Rails backend to save it to a user's profile. Bookmark#create requires authentication, which I use the `simple_token_authentication` gem for with Devise.

My question now is how I can check whether a user is logged in and is authorized to create a bookmark?

I know that there a many similar questions (like this one: [Chrome Extension + Devise + Rails App - Making authenticated requests from extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681098/chrome-extension-devise-rails-app-making-authenticated-requests-from-exten)), however the answer is not very detailed.

This it my first Chrome extension, so I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Hey, did you, by any chance, manage to solve your problem ?